# chat in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad

is it possible to create chat application like gmail (message sending is enough) in iphone sdk?any help?

Comment: There is a reason why so many questions about 'chat in iPhone SDK' go unanswered...

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocol like STOMP and use an Active MQ server if you want a lobby chat server. Made a proof of conecpt for a while ago which works perfect for easy text transmission.